# Make view to adjust size from bottom if device screen resolution is lower

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I have a UIViewController in my Storyboard.

[image]

The "light gray" view is set to fixed height but Im worried if it wont fit in a smaller phone screen.

Is there a way to anchor the "light gray" view so the height will be adjusted automatically if the screen is smaller? I guess I would have to adjust also de "Test" button.

> Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

There certainly is a way, and it begins with `AutoLayout`.

Here's a nice tutorial to get you started: https://www.weheartswift.com/auto-layout-101/